# Laravel Eloquent Case Sensitive Relationships

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

Hi SO I'm having real issues with some Laravel Eloquent relationships which I can only guess are being caused by a case-sensitive relation and I'm hoping somebody here can help!

Here are the models that I'm having the issues with:

```
class DeliveryManifestLines extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'manifests';

    public function sapDelivery()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Delivery', 'DocNum', 'sap_delivery');
    }

}


class Delivery extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'sap';
    protected $table = 'ODLN';
    protected $primaryKey = 'DocNum';

    public function deliveryManifest() {
      return $this->belongsTo('DeliveryManifest', 'DocNum', 'sap_delivery');
    }

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Address', 'Address', 'ShipToCode')->where('CardCode', $this->CardCode)->where('AdresType', 'S');
    }

    public function geolocation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('GeoLocation', 'Address', 'ShipToCode')->where('CardCode', $this->CardCode)->where('AdresType', 'S')->where('Lat', '>', 0)->where('Lng', '>', 0);
    }
}

class Address extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'sap';
    protected $table = 'CRD1';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Address';

    public function delivery() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Delivery', 'Address', 'ShipToCode');
    }

}
```

Here's the code in my controller that is supposed to fetch some of the above models from the DB.

```
$deliveries = DeliveryManifestLines::with('sapDelivery')->where('manifest_date', $date))->get();

foreach ($deliveries as $delivery) {
    $delivery->sapDelivery->load('address');
}
```

I'm using the "`->load('address)`" line as no matter what I tried I could not get eager loading to work with "`sapDelivery.address`"

In 99% of cases the address is loaded successfully from the DB but I have come across one case in which I am experiencing an issue that I can only think is being caused by case-sensitivity.

Using Laravel DebugBar I can see that my application is executing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM [CRD1] WHERE [CardCode] = 'P437' AND [AdresType] = 'S' AND [CRD1].[Address] IN ('The Pizza Factory (topping)')
```

When I dump the contents of `$delivery->sapDelivery` in this occurrence the address relation is NULL, however, when I paste the SQL statement into my DB console and execute it manually I get the expected row returned.

The only difference I can see between this one address and the thousands of others that are working is that there is a case difference between the Address fields:

In the CRD1 table the Address field for the effected/expected row is "The Pizza Factory (Topping)" but the eloquent relationship is using AND [CRD1].[Address] IN ('The Pizza Factory (topping)') to try and find it I'm aware that SQL is case-insensitive be default but I can't think of any other reason why this one row is behaving differently to the others.

Does anybody have any other ideas as to what could be causing this issue and suggest any possible solutions or confirm either way my theory of case sensitivity being the culprit.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think I have tracked this down to the matchOneOrMany function in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany.php where a dictionary of relations is built up and searched using isset() which is case sensitive.

I'm yet to come up with a fix / work-around so any ideas/pointers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So After giving this problem little thought over the past few months I revisited the issue today and found some very useful code on [laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/04-24-2014-case-sensitive-eager-loading-and-string-based-foreign-key-issue) by somebody experiencing the same issue I found myself with.

I've built on MattApril's solution to provide the least hacky way I can think of to provide a way to offer case insensitive relationships in laravel.

To achieve this you need to add a few new classes which utilise the strtolower() function to create lower case keys which allows the isset() function used in the relationships to find differently cased but matching keys:

**ModelCI.php** (app\Models\Eloquent\ModelCI.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Eloquent;

use App\Models\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToCI;
use App\Models\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyCI;
use App\Models\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneCI;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


abstract class ModelCI extends Model
{
    /**
     * Define a one-to-many relationship.
     *
     * @param string $related
     * @param string $foreignKey
     * @param string $localKey
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function hasManyCI($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
    {
        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $instance = new $related();

        $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

        return new HasManyCI($instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey);
    }

        /**
         * Define a one-to-one relationship.
         *
         * @param  string  $related
         * @param  string  $foreignKey
         * @param  string  $localKey
         * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
         */
        public function hasOneCI($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
        {
            $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

            $instance = new $related;

            $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

            return new HasOneCI($instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey);
        }

    /**
     * Define an inverse one-to-one or many relationship.
     *
     * @param  string  $related
     * @param  string  $foreignKey
     * @param  string  $otherKey
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function belongsToCI($related, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null)
    {
      // If no relation name was given, we will use this debug backtrace to extract
      // the calling method's name and use that as the relationship name as most
      // of the time this will be what we desire to use for the relationships.
      if (is_null($relation))
      {
        list(, $caller) = debug_backtrace(false, 2);

        $relation = $caller['function'];
      }

      // If no foreign key was supplied, we can use a backtrace to guess the proper
      // foreign key name by using the name of the relationship function, which
      // when combined with an "_id" should conventionally match the columns.
      if (is_null($foreignKey))
      {
        $foreignKey = snake_case($relation).'_id';
      }

      $instance = new $related;

      // Once we have the foreign key names, we'll just create a new Eloquent query
      // for the related models and returns the relationship instance which will
      // actually be responsible for retrieving and hydrating every relations.
      $query = $instance->newQuery();

      $otherKey = $otherKey ?: $instance->getKeyName();

      return new BelongsToCI($query, $this, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
    }
}
```

**BelongsToCI.php** (app\Models\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToCI.php)

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Eloquent\Relations;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class BelongsToCI extends BelongsTo {
    /**
     * Match the eagerly loaded results to their parents.
     *
     * @param  array   $models
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  $results
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return array
     */
    public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
    {
        $foreign = $this->foreignKey;

        $other = $this->otherKey;

        // First we will get to build a dictionary of the child models by their primary
        // key of the relationship, then we can easily match the children back onto
        // the parents using that dictionary and the primary key of the children.
        $dictionary = array();

        foreach ($results as $result)
        {
            $dictionary[strtolower($result->getAttribute($other))] = $result;
        }

        // Once we have the dictionary constructed, we can loop through all the parents
        // and match back onto their children using these keys of the dictionary and
        // the primary key of the children to map them onto the correct instances.
        foreach ($models as $model)
        {
            if (isset($dictionary[strtolower($model->$foreign)]))
            {
                $model->setRelation($relation, $dictionary[strtolower($model->$foreign)]);
            }
        }

        return $models;
    }

}
```

**HasManyCI.php** (app\Models\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyCI.php)

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Eloquent\Relations;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class HasManyCI extends HasMany {
    /**
        * Build model dictionary keyed by the relation's foreign key.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  $results
        * @return array
        */
     protected function buildDictionary(Collection $results)
     {
             $dictionary = array();

             $foreign = $this->getPlainForeignKey();

             // First we will create a dictionary of models keyed by the foreign key of the
             // relationship as this will allow us to quickly access all of the related
             // models without having to do nested looping which will be quite slow.
             foreach ($results as $result)
             {
                     $dictionary[strtolower($result->{$foreign})][] = $result;
             }

             return $dictionary;
     }

    /**
        * Match the eagerly loaded results to their many parents.
        *
        * @param  array   $models
        * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  $results
        * @param  string  $relation
        * @param  string  $type
        * @return array
        */
     protected function matchOneOrMany(array $models, Collection $results, $relation, $type)
     {
             $dictionary = $this->buildDictionary($results);


             // Once we have the dictionary we can simply spin through the parent models to
             // link them up with their children using the keyed dictionary to make the
             // matching very convenient and easy work. Then we'll just return them.
             foreach ($models as $model)
             {
                     $key = strtolower( $model->getAttribute($this->localKey) );
                     if (isset($dictionary[$key]))
                     {
                             $value = $this->getRelationValue($dictionary, $key, $type);
                             $model->setRelation($relation, $value);
                     }
             }

             return $models;
     }

}
```

**HasOneCI.php** (app\Models\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneCI.php)

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Eloquent\Relations;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class HasOneCI extends HasOne {

    /**
     * Match the eagerly loaded results to their many parents.
     *
     * @param  array   $models
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  $results
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @param  string  $type
     * @return array
     */
    protected function matchOneOrMany(array $models, Collection $results, $relation, $type)
    {
        $dictionary = $this->buildDictionary($results);

        // Once we have the dictionary we can simply spin through the parent models to
        // link them up with their children using the keyed dictionary to make the
        // matching very convenient and easy work. Then we'll just return them.
        foreach ($models as $model)
        {
            $key = strtolower($model->getAttribute($this->localKey));

            if (isset($dictionary[$key]))
            {
                $value = $this->getRelationValue($dictionary, $key, $type);

                $model->setRelation($relation, $value);
            }
        }

        return $models;
    }

    /**
     * Build model dictionary keyed by the relation's foreign key.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  $results
     * @return array
     */
    protected function buildDictionary(Collection $results)
    {
        $dictionary = array();

        $foreign = strtolower($this->getPlainForeignKey());

        // First we will create a dictionary of models keyed by the foreign key of the
        // relationship as this will allow us to quickly access all of the related
        // models without having to do nested looping which will be quite slow.
        foreach ($results as $result)
        {
            $dictionary[$result->{$foreign}][] = $result;
        }

        return $dictionary;
    }

}
```

To utilise the new classes you must define a relationship as so:

```
$this->belongsToCI('Model');
```

or

```
$this->hasManyCI('Model');
```

or

```
$this->hasOneCI('Model');
```

Comment: Quick note for anyone that comes across this; as of Laravel 5.4 the "otherKey" property in the BelongsTo relationship has been renamed to "ownerKey", be sure to change that.

Answer (score -2):

Eloquent uses internal associative arrays to map and link the related records to their parents and in cases with string foreign keys and difference in uppercase vs lowercase, some of the related records will not be mapped.

I recently came across the same problem and decided to wrap a solution in a composer package. 
https://github.com/TishoTM/eloquent-ci-relations

After installing the composer package, you can simply use the trait inside the eloquent models without changing anything else on the relation methods within the model.

`use \TishoTM\Eloquent\Concerns\HasCiRelationships;`